# Error creating bean with name 'hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource

Tags: spring, hibernate

I`ve started learning JSF, and i have configured it with hibernate and spring.
Tomcat does not throw "Error Error creating bean with name 'hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource"

Here`s my appContext.xml:

> http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
>           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
>           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
>           http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd">

```
<!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing 
    infrastructure -->

<!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
<annotation-driven />

<!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving 
    up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
<resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />


<beans:bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
    destroy-method="close">
    <beans:property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <beans:property name="url"
        value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Users" />
    <beans:property name="username" value="root" />
    <beans:property name="password" value="adminss" />
</beans:bean>

<!-- Hibernate 4 SessionFactory Bean definition -->
<beans:bean id="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <beans:property name="annotatedClasses">
        <beans:list>
            <beans:value>users.Users</beans:value>
        </beans:list>
    </beans:property>
    <beans:property name="hibernateProperties">
        <beans:props>
            <beans:prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
            </beans:prop>
            <beans:prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</beans:prop>
        </beans:props>
    </beans:property>
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="usersDAO"
    class="users.UsersDAOImpl">
    <beans:property name="sessionFactory"
        ref="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory" />
</beans:bean>
<beans:bean id="usersService"
    class="users.UsersServiceImpl">
    <beans:property name="usersDAO" ref="usersDAO"></beans:property>
</beans:bean>

<context:component-scan base-package="users" />

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

<beans:bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <beans:property name="sessionFactory"
        ref="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory" />
</beans:bean>
```

Hers`s POM.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>JSF_Spring_Hibernate</groupId>
<artifactId>JSF_Spring_Hibernate</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<properties>

    <!-- Generic properties -->
    <java.version>1.6</java.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>

    <!-- Spring -->
    <spring-framework.version>4.0.3.RELEASE</spring-framework.version>
    <aspectj.version>1.7.4</aspectj.version>

    <!-- Hibernate / JPA -->
    <hibernate.version>4.3.5.Final</hibernate.version>

    <!-- JSF Version -->
    <jsf.version>2.2.10</jsf.version>

    <!-- Logging -->
    <logback.version>1.0.13</logback.version>
    <slf4j.version>1.7.5</slf4j.version>

</properties>

<dependencies>
    <!-- Spring and Transactions -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- @Inject -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
        <version>1</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- AspectJ -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
        <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Spring ORM support -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Hibernate -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.9</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- JSF Dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
        <version>${jsf.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
        <version>${jsf.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Logging with SLF4J & LogBack -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        <version>${logback.version}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- http://repo1.maven.org/maven -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.el</groupId>
        <artifactId>el-ri</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
        <version>7.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
</build>
```

Here`s log:

```
kwi 05, 2018 10:30:03 AM org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader initWebApplicationContext
```

SEVERE: Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: No identifier specified for entity: users.Users
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1553)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:684)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4579)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5041)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)

and Rpository class:

```
@Repository
```

public class UsersDAOImpl implements UsersDAO {

```
private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UsersDAOImpl.class);

@Autowired
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
    this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
}

@Override
public void addUser(Users s) {
    Session session= this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    session.persist(s);
logger.info("User saved successfully, User details" + " " + s); 

}
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Override
public List<Users> listUsers() {
    Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    List<Users> usersList = session.createQuery("FROM Users").list();
    for (Users u : usersList) {
        logger.info("Users list" + " " +u);
    }
    return usersList;
}
```

}

Comment: You don't configure JSF to use spring and hibernate. JSF has no knowledge of either of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see in log

> nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: No identifier
>   specified for entity: users.Users

So the most probably that you are missing a field annotated with @Id for `Users` entity.